# Primary and Foreign Keys being same MySQL shows exception

Tags: mysql, sql-server, database, postgresql, mysql-workbench

When executing the following lines of code its throwing error.

```
CREATE TABLE USERS (
USERNAME VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
PASSWORD VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
ENABLED SMALLINT,
PRIMARY KEY (USERNAME)
);

CREATE TABLE AUTHORITIES (
USERNAME VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
AUTHORITY VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
FOREIGN KEY (USERNAME) REFERENCES USERS
);
```

and the exception I got is:

> 1215 Cannot create foreign key constraint

Foreign key and primary key being same enough this throws error.

kindly help

Answer (score 1):

Does making the reference more specific work:

```
CREATE TABLE AUTHORITIES (
USERNAME VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
AUTHORITY VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
FOREIGN KEY (USERNAME) REFERENCES USERS(USERNAME)
);
```

The doc here(http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html) seems to have it in the form `table(column)`

Comment: That's good news, at first when I saw the fieldname `USERNAME` and tablename `USERS` I thought they might be reserved words, but they were not on the reserved word list on the dev.mysql.com site.  Do you mind marking this as the answer?